# Is there any css prefix for Edge?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, vendor-prefix

Edge does not support this prefix, but IE does support the prefix.

[image]

**-ms-overflow-y: hidden;**

Answer (score 1):

Edge doesn't support the `-ms-` prefix for anything but its own Windows-specific CSS properties.

`-ms-overflow-y` doesn't need to exist anyway. No version of IE, let alone Edge, requires the prefix, and I don't know why Microsoft added it to IE when it's always supported the unprefixed `overflow-y` just fine. `-ms-overflow-y` is just a waste of space in your CSS and you should remove it. For that matter you should probably remove all the other prefixed values, *and* the `overflow-x: hidden` declaration too, and replace everything with a single `overflow: hidden` line.

Comment: You should not be seeing two scroll bars on your web pages like your picture shows. You are doing something wrong... or your zoom preferences between your test browsers differ.